# Extract JSON including key with jq command

Tags: json, jq

HERE is sample json file.

sample.json

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "name": "app1"
    },
    {
      "name": "app2"
    },
    {
      "name": "app3"
    }
  ],
  "test": [
    {
      "name": "test1"
    },
    {
      "name": "test2"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to divide the above JSON file into the following two files.
I want to manage the entire configuration file with one JSON, divide the file when necessary and give it to the tool.

apps.json

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "name": "app1"
    },
    {
      "name": "app2"
    },
    {
      "name": "app3"
    }
}
```

test.json

```
{
  "test": [
    {
      "name": "test1"
    },
    {
      "name": "test1"
    }
  ]
}
```

---

`jq .apps sample.json` outputs only value.

```
[
// Not contain the key
  {
    "name": "app1"
  },
  {
    "name": "app2"
  },
  {
    "name": "app3"
  }
]
```

Can you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Construct](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#ObjectConstruction%3A%7B%7D) a new object using `{x}` which is a shorthand for `{x: .x}`.

```sh
jq '{apps}' sample.json
```

```json
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "name": "app1"
    },
    {
      "name": "app2"
    },
    {
      "name": "app3"
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/YoOjENRFVu)

And likewise with `{test}`.

Comment: Solved : )
Thank you for your quick and nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
{apps}, {test}
```

Demo

https://jqplay.org/s/P_9cc2uANV